# Python error when renaming files in windows

Tags: python, rename

I am attempting to give all the jpg files in a folder a random name, so they appear in semi random order on my digital picture frame

This is the code I'm trying to use:

```
import os
import random

for filename in os.listdir("."):
    hold = random.randint(1,100000)
    f=str(hold)+'.jpg'

    if(filename.endswith('.jpg') or (filename.endswith('.JPG'))):
        os.rename(filename,f)
```

However when I run it I get:

```
WindowsError: [Error 82] The directory or file cannot be created.
```

Everything I've seen makes it look like my code should work, I don't know why it won't run.

<strike>EDIT: It seems like its due to the fact that there are spaces in the name of the file I'm trying to rename</strike>

EDIT2:I was copying the files to an SD card formatted as FAT and the folder I was running it in had the maximum number of items in it. I solved it by moving a couple of the files to a subdirectory.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! The way we marked questions as 'Solved' around here is to [mark an answer as accepted](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#howtoask) ([even if it's an answer you provided yourself](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/31809/147331))!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was copying the files to an SD card formatted as FAT and the folder I was running it in had the maximum number of items in it. I solved it by moving a couple of the files to a subdirectory.

Answer (score 0):

Probably your rename is failing. Try adding some debug print to your code and see, when exactly it is failing. Before renaming add `print 'Renaming %s to %s' % (filename, f)` and see, when the rename fails.

Answer (score 0):

The problem as far as I can see it is that the variable filename isn't an actual file, but a string. os.listdir() returns a list of strings that are the filenames in that folder. You need to use open("w", filename) to open the file and then rename it and then save it.

Answer (score 0):

Taking a look at the documentation for [`os.rename()`](http://docs.python.org/library/os.html#module-os), in Windows, it will raise `OSError` if the file you're trying to rename it to already exists (as there's no way to implement an atomic rename on the OS).  That is to say, **if the file you're renaming your JPEG to is already present in the directory, `os.rename` will fail on Windows.**

It could be the case that you're attempting to rename a file in your current directory to another file that already exists.  You would have to add code to check against that, which isn't too difficult:

```
filelist = os.listdir('.')
for filename in filelist:
    hold = random.randint(1,100000)
    f=str(hold)+'.jpg'

 if filename.lower().endswith('.jpg') and f not in filelist:
    os.rename(filename,f)
```